# Alert Dialog is not showing when I call it from a VPNService class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-alertdialog

I am creating a VPN Local Service on Android studio as my Thesis project for my university. Specifically, i have the main class on my Java File which is VPNLocalService extends Service, in that class i have another one VpnRunnable implements Runnable. In that class I check if the network packets are TCP or UDP and forward them accordingly.

When I check the packets, I want to display a Dialog with a message when the packet has a local address as a destination.
[In the yellow underline is the code to display the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jba4J.png)

Im sending the code snipend to get an understanding(I removed some code from the methods that are not necessary for this to make it smaller)

```
public class LocalVPNService extends VpnService
{
    private static final String TAG = LocalVPNService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String VPN_ADDRESS = "10.0.0.2"; // Only IPv4 support for now
    private static final String VPN_ROUTE = "0.0.0.0"; // Intercept everything

    public static final String BROADCAST_VPN_STATE = "xyz.hexene.localvpn.VPN_STATE";

    private static boolean isRunning = false;

    private ParcelFileDescriptor vpnInterface = null;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet> deviceToNetworkUDPQueue;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet> deviceToNetworkTCPQueue;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ByteBuffer> networkToDeviceQueue;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    private Selector udpSelector;
    private Selector tcpSelector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        isRunning = true;



        setupVPN();
        try
        {
            udpSelector = Selector.open();
            tcpSelector = Selector.open();
            deviceToNetworkUDPQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
            deviceToNetworkTCPQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
            networkToDeviceQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            executorService.submit(new UDPInput(networkToDeviceQueue, udpSelector));
            executorService.submit(new UDPOutput(deviceToNetworkUDPQueue, udpSelector, this));
            executorService.submit(new TCPInput(networkToDeviceQueue, tcpSelector));
            executorService.submit(new TCPOutput(deviceToNetworkTCPQueue, networkToDeviceQueue, tcpSelector, this));
            executorService.submit(new VPNRunnable(vpnInterface.getFileDescriptor(),
                    deviceToNetworkUDPQueue, deviceToNetworkTCPQueue, networkToDeviceQueue));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(BROADCAST_VPN_STATE).putExtra("running", true));
            Log.i(TAG, "Started");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO: Here and elsewhere, we should explicitly notify the user of any errors
            // and suggest that they stop the service, since we can't do it ourselves
            Log.e(TAG, "Error starting service", e);
            cleanup();
        }
    }

    private void setupVPN()
    {
        if (vpnInterface == null)
        {
            Builder builder = new Builder();
            builder.addAddress(VPN_ADDRESS, 32);
            //builder.addRoute(VPN_ROUTE, 0);

            builder.addRoute("10.0.0.0", 8);
            builder.addRoute("172.16.0.0", 12);
            builder.addRoute("192.168.0.0", 16);

            vpnInterface = builder.setSession(getString(R.string.app_name)).setConfigureIntent(pendingIntent).establish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public static boolean isRunning()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void cleanup()
    {    }

    // TODO: Move this to a "utils" class for reuse
    private static void closeResources(Closeable... resources)
    {}

    private class VPNRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivitymanager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //PackageManager packageManager = Context.getPackageManager();

        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        private final String TAG = VPNRunnable.class.getSimpleName();

        private FileDescriptor vpnFileDescriptor;

        private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet> deviceToNetworkUDPQueue;
        private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet> deviceToNetworkTCPQueue;
        private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ByteBuffer> networkToDeviceQueue;

        public VPNRunnable(FileDescriptor vpnFileDescriptor,
                           ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet> deviceToNetworkUDPQueue,
                           ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet> deviceToNetworkTCPQueue,
                           ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ByteBuffer> networkToDeviceQueue)
        {
            this.vpnFileDescriptor = vpnFileDescriptor;
            this.deviceToNetworkUDPQueue = deviceToNetworkUDPQueue;
            this.deviceToNetworkTCPQueue = deviceToNetworkTCPQueue;
            this.networkToDeviceQueue = networkToDeviceQueue;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Started");

            int uid;
            int isSamePort = 0;
            //List<Integer> ownerUIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            Map<Integer, String> uidToNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

            String packageName;

            FileChannel vpnInput = new FileInputStream(vpnFileDescriptor).getChannel();
            FileChannel vpnOutput = new FileOutputStream(vpnFileDescriptor).getChannel();

            try
            {
                ByteBuffer bufferToNetwork = null;
                boolean dataSent = true;
                boolean dataReceived;
                while (!Thread.interrupted())
                {
                    if (dataSent)
                        bufferToNetwork = ByteBufferPool.acquire();
                    else
                        bufferToNetwork.clear();

                    // TODO: Block when not connected
                    int readBytes = vpnInput.read(bufferToNetwork);
                    if (readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        dataSent = true;
                        bufferToNetwork.flip();
                        Packet packet = new Packet(bufferToNetwork);
                        if (packet.isUDP())
                        {
                            uid = connectivitymanager.getConnectionOwnerUid (IPPROTO_UDP,new InetSocketAddress(packet.ip4Header.sourceAddress.getHostAddress(), packet.udpHeader.sourcePort), new InetSocketAddress(packet.ip4Header.destinationAddress.getHostAddress(), packet.udpHeader.destinationPort));


                            if(!uidToNameMap.containsKey(uid) && packageManager.getNameForUid(uid) != null){
                                Log.w("Conne", "Im inside the if statement");
                                //ownerUIDs.add(uid);
                                packageName = packageManager.getNameForUid(uid);


                                uidToNameMap.put(uid, packageName);

                                //An intent is used in order to display the dialog for informing the user that an app tries to
                                //access the local network

                                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(LocalVPNService.this, NetworkAccessDialog.class);
                                dialogIntent.putExtra("packageName", packageName);
                                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // You need this flag to start an Activity from a Service
                                startActivity(dialogIntent);


                                //Log.w("Connection","UIDS: " + Integer.toString(uid) + " Package name" + packageName);
                                Log.w("connection", "ATTENTION!: " + packageName + " tries to access local network");

                            }



                            //Log.w("Ip packets", "\n\nIPV4 UDP PACKET:   " + packet.ip4Header.destinationAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n\n");
                            deviceToNetworkUDPQueue.offer(packet);
                        }
                        else if (packet.isTCP())
                        {
                            uid = connectivitymanager.getConnectionOwnerUid (IPPROTO_TCP,new InetSocketAddress(packet.ip4Header.sourceAddress.getHostAddress(), packet.tcpHeader.sourcePort), new InetSocketAddress(packet.ip4Header.destinationAddress.getHostAddress(), packet.tcpHeader.destinationPort));


                            //i hold all the uids-names of the apps that send traffic
                            if(!uidToNameMap.containsKey(uid) && packageManager.getNameForUid(uid) != null){
                                //Log.w("Conne", "Im inside the if statement");
                                //ownerUIDs.add(uid);
                                packageName = packageManager.getNameForUid(uid);

                                uidToNameMap.put(uid, packageName);

                                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(LocalVPNService.this, NetworkAccessDialog.class);
                                dialogIntent.putExtra("packageName", packageName);
                                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // You need this flag to start an Activity from a Service
                                startActivity(dialogIntent);



                                Log.w("connection", "ATTENTION!: " + packageName + " tries to access local network");

                            }
                            //Log.w("Ip packets", "\n\nIPV4 TCP PACKET:   " + packet.ip4Header.destinationAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n\n");
                            deviceToNetworkTCPQueue.offer(packet);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Unknown packet type");
                            Log.w(TAG, packet.ip4Header.toString());
                            dataSent = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataSent = false;
                    }

                    ByteBuffer bufferFromNetwork = networkToDeviceQueue.poll();
                    if (bufferFromNetwork != null)
                    {
                        bufferFromNetwork.flip();
                        while (bufferFromNetwork.hasRemaining())
                            vpnOutput.write(bufferFromNetwork);
                        dataReceived = true;

                        ByteBufferPool.release(bufferFromNetwork);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataReceived = false;
                    }

                    // TODO: Sleep-looping is not very battery-friendly, consider blocking instead
                    // Confirm if throughput with ConcurrentQueue is really higher compared to BlockingQueue
                    if (!dataSent && !dataReceived)
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "Stopping");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, e.toString(), e);
            }
            finally
            {
                closeResources(vpnInput, vpnOutput);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I read that since i want to display from a Service i need to create an Activity to be displayed

[This is the activity i created for the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRJMd.png)

I also made sure the activity is reffered on the manifest file

[Like this on the manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUBrC.png)

However, whatever i try, the dialog is not displayed and i get no errors. For some reason that i cannot find, the Activity is not reached iven though i "Call" it in my from the service as shown in the first image.

Is it wrong to choose dialog for this? I read somewhere that notifications hould be used with services but im not sure and dialog is what i want as a UI

I need your help, I hope my explanation is clear enough and understandable.

I thank you all very much in advance for any answers that will help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

1. Check below line is reachable and giving logs, startActivity(...) should be called:

`Log.w("connection", "ATTENTION!: " + packageName + " tries to access local network");`

2. Dialog is only visible when you create in activity or fragment

I will try to test your codes later, I will let you know